# Laptop not compliant with package profiles through Landscape

Tags: networking, 18.04, landscape, aws, macbook-air

I installed Ubuntu 18.04 on a MacBook Air for testing purposes, and linked it to my free Landscape license, running off AWS. I have installed the third-party drivers in the Ubuntu ISO, and Wi-Fi works on the laptop.

Security groups (IP filtering) on the AWS server are set to allow HTTP, HTTPS, ICMP, and SSH from the IP of my router.

There are two simple package profiles I have set by default: installation of emacs and the Chromium browser. For some reason, the laptop can't run either of them. Landscape tries and fails. However, it doesn't seem to be the case that it isn't receiving the commands: remote locking of user accounts on the MacBook from Landscape works just fine. And the MacBook can access and download packages and package updates just fine, as well.

Can anyone see what I'm missing? I can't.

Comment: Upon further inspection I found this in the log files every time it tries to apply packages:

```"WARNING  [MainThread] Couldn't download hash=>id database: Server returned HTTP code 404"```

All documentation I can find to solve this problem is for Xenial Xerus, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the hash ID database on the server wasn't populated with entries for Ubuntu 18.04 Bionic Beaver. I edited `/opt/canonical/landscape/configs/standalone/hash_id_databases.conf` and added entries for [bionic] and [bionic-arm], and ran `/opt/canonical/landscape/scripts/hash_id_databases.sh`, which solved my problem.